# Passing Variable in PHP Authentication Basic Realm Message

Tags: php

Stuck on trying to pass a variable in Basic Realm authentication message

```
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=“Invalid password for User “.$userid.’);
```

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you're using smart quotes, use plain ol' apostrophes and quotes instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Invalid password for User" '.$userid);
```

Your variable must be outside of string quotes and connected to string with `.`

**Edit:**

Based on what you ask this should also work:

```
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Invalid password for User" '.$_GET['variable']);
```

check if you have a value in your `variable`

Comment: It works when I'm using a prefilled variable, but doesn't work if the variable is pegged to $_GET['variable']; - any ideas why?

Comment: try echo $_GET['variable']. probably it is empty.

Comment: And your $_GET['variable'] echos a variable? If yes can you please show me the output?

Comment: The reason why it doesn't work is because the Authentication is prioritised, so the $_GET doesn't get executed before the Authentication. Wonder if there's a workaround for this.

Comment: did you try to assign $_GET to a variable which you are going to use in the header? Maybe this small _hack_ works.